# How to remove item from List on Android using SQLiteOpenHelper?

Tags: java, android, listview

Currently, in another`class`, I need to delete 1 item when I upload success a file call `deleteCallWhenUploadSuccess`.
In this class, I using `fileName` to determined item need to delete.

But it doesn't delete item in ListView from Layout `activity_call_history.xml`

In DAO class I delete with code:

```
public void deleteCallWhenUploadSuccess(String fileNameWhis)
{
    db = callDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String where = CallDatabaseHelper.FILE_NAME + "='" + fileNameWhis + "'";
    db.delete(CallDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, where, null);
}
```

And in other class I using it:

`DAO.deleteCallWhenUploadSuccess(filename);`

I write code to remove an item on ListView in event onActionItemClicked.

On the `DAO class` I start to delete an item with rowId:

```
public void deleteCallV2(int rowId) {
    db = callDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+CallDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME+" where rowId = "+String.valueOf(rowId),null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    this.rowId = CallDatabaseHelper.ROW_ID +"="+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallDatabaseHelper.ROW_ID));
    }
    db.delete(CallDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, this.rowId, null);

}
```

Code I used to delete item in ListView of Layout historyAdapter write code in HistoryFragment.java, I was comment in code to easy read:

```
@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.deleteAction:
            // Calls getSelectedIds method from ListViewAdapter Class
            selected = historyAdapter
                    .getSelectedIds();
            // Captures all selected ids with a loop
            for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                    Call selecteditem = historyAdapter
                            .getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                    // Remove selected items following the ids

                    historyAdapter.remove(selecteditem);
                }
            }
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new HistoryFragment()).commit();
            // Close CAB
            mode.finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.allAction:
            historyAdapter.toggleAll(listView);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Đã chọn tất cả", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

But it only work when I select item with long press and select item or select all to delete. It using ID to delete item.

Comment: The hard was language me. I was not understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't got much but according to the heading of the question which says to remove an item in list I can suggest you to use notifyDataSetChanged() whenever you are removing a view so that your listview could update itself whenever its changed

A little code which demonstrate this task is

```
adapter = new MyListAdapter(this);
lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
    adb.setTitle("Delete?");
    adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + position);
    final int positionToRemove = position;
    adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            MyDataObject.remove(positionToRemove);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }});
    adb.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want when a function UploadSucess = true then it will auto delete rows(item) in ListView. Your code is when onItemClick it will delete rows.

Comment: so just check with an if condition if(UploadSucess) `{delete the so element and notifyDatasetChanged();}` The basic thing which will be done will be this only